# Extract data from HP QC to excel using API

Tags: javascript, php, jira-rest-api, alm, hp-quality-center

I need to extract data from HP QC from backend using PHP or javascript. The data needs to be put on database or excel sheet.
Is there any API to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite common is nowadays the QC REST API, references you can get from the below link at HP:

[http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#Overview.htm](http://QC%20official%20REST%20API)

With this QC ALM you should be able to retrieve whatever data from QC backend. I am doing that using python requests module and python scripts:

[http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/](http://Official%20requests%20documentation)

Anyway you have to write a bit of code before getting your goal done!

Another API that is also possible to use for this task is the VAPI-XP, mostly used in the past, but also suitable for your goal.
Official link below:
[http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/online_help/Content/UG/c_vapixp_overview.htm](http://VAPI-XP%20QC)

Hope this clarify your query! Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Will Requests help in extracting from HP QC?

Comment: Requests is a python module that I used to send REST messages (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE) and to initialize a session to the server. For instance requests is something like curl (if you are more familiar with Linux).  In the end you have to pick up one language (for instance PHP as you wrote) and check the better way to send REST message to the Server :-) It will take time, but the automation is worth in this case :-)

Comment: Could you please close this question now? Do you need additional clarifications? Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: I am a novice. 
Need one help. any example regarding implementation in any language?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/barkady/26d077fa8556d7d987cb Here is a full REST client implemented, but as said you have to choose the best language for you. I did it in python as said. Anyway I think my answer above is the correct answer to your query :-) After you start with the first steps (connection/login and so on), you will see that it will go fast! Have a nice day.

Comment: I have now connected properly but unable to filter on basis of different columns. How to do that?

Comment: @Kumarshaswat: you should properly write a new question with description, otherwise is difficult to follow. Anyway what you can do is after you send a REST message, you are getting an xml (for instance) back. Then you can parse that and get all the values you need, ordered as you need :-) for instance I used python etree to parse the xml file. Below link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Sorry for the description.
I mean, while extracting data from the HP QC, we are extracting each and every column of the defect table. I want to extract data of few columns in xml format. Is it possible?

Comment: You can write multiple values in your query:    GET URL?query={name[Name];project[PROJ];owner[You]}     and so on, it will help you in chain a query. Hope this clarify...otherwise as above you can GET a huge xml and then parsing with whatever languages :-)

Comment: Please check also the REST API library from HP :-)